# WORDPRESS Simple Query

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have a category query, and in my category query I want to get product (only one) by queried category id (or name or whatsoever)
I start query:

```
<?wpsc_start_category_query(array('category_group'=> get_option('wpsc_default_category'))); ?>
```

and then try to use get_posts() function to get product:

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
 'posts_per_page' => 1,
 'tax_query' => array(
  array(
  'taxonomy' => 'wpsc_product_category',
  'field' => 'id',
  'terms' => $aka
 )));
$cat1_posts = get_posts($args);
```

where $aka is:

```
$aka = '[wpsc_category_id]';
```

but when I echo $cat1_posts[0]->ID; it only shows my last product ID for every category. what is the problem? echoing only [wpsc_category_id] works perfect.
I tried EVERYTHING for the last few days. I will buy you cookies for help

I've got to idea, that I need foreach or anything like this

Comment: IMPOSSIBLE THAT NOBODY CAN HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the get_terms() function. So something like this (untested)

```php
<?php
    //for each category, show latest post
    $cat_args=array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'ASC'
       );
    $categories = get_terms( 'wpsc_product_category');
      foreach($categories as $category) { 
        $args=array(
          'showposts' => 1,
          'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
          'wpsc_product_category' => array($category->slug)
        );
        $posts=get_posts($args);
          if ($posts) {
            echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
            foreach($posts as $post) {
              setup_postdata($post); ?>
              <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
              <?php
            } // foreach($posts
          } // if ($posts
        } // foreach($categories
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!! very very and etc ))

works perfect, if we don't count category image, but usual categories don't have thumbnails, whereas my wpsc categories does. so it's different question I guess

 THan kyou

Comment: Ammmm no doesnot work, I tought it was working but actually it does same my code does. queries only last product for every category.
even if it's not in this category

Comment: I changed  
      'wpsc_product_category' => array($category->slug) to 
      'wpsc_product_category' => $category->slug
and now it works

Comment: only . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . doesnot work

the href is empty in html source

Comment: just used get_term_link( $category->slug, 'wpsc_product_category' ) 

:)